# capture mobile(real device) traffic on laptop fiddler

Tags: android, proxy, fiddler-everywhere

I am trying to capture my mobile traffic on my laptop fiddler.

I followed the steps provided in below link.
https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/get-started/mobile-traffic/configure-android

Issue is I am losing internet on my mobile after adding proxy.

My mobile and laptop are on same WIFI network

Comment: unable to browse or use any mobile apps

Comment: Did you follow the step to install the certificate on your Android device?

Comment: I am unable to browse the ipv4.fiddler:8866 on my device as well

Comment: If you try with emulator on your laptop and it works, then leaning towards a WiFi/network issue.

Comment: Make sure to also disable "Secure DNS" on your phone. Note that even if the connection works most apps will not have internet connection if you enable TLS interception in Fiddler (installing the certificate has no effect by default). Make sure that your WiFi does allow device-to-device communication. A lot of WiFis deny such traffic by default.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that,

1. On your real mobile, you have "allowed remote computer to connect".
2. "Your laptop's IP address" is configured as a proxy on your mobile manually.
3. Your mobile's proxy port number is configured 8866 manually.
4. Try pinging your phone IP address from your computer.

If it is still not working maybe try "fiddler classic" instead of "Fiddler Everywhere". Please setup your Android device to use "Fiddler" tool as a proxy. Then you can use fiddler tool for debugging on Windows. You just need to install fiddler root certificate.

Refer below link:
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-android-traffic-with-fiddler

And to capture iOS Traffic with Fiddler: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-ios-traffic-with-fiddler

Comment: The Fiddler Android tutorial is simply wrong as the step `Install the certificate on your device.` does install the certificate on the device but this certificate will be ignored by most apps. Therefore HTTPS interception will not work the way this tutorial describes.

Comment: @Robert Then, what should do?

Comment: @4rigener The possibilities how to intercept HTTPS traffic on Android are shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler/62731432#62731432

Comment: @Robert This problem can be solved by your answer? It's about some traffic not caputred, not all. https://www.telerik.com/forums/can-not-catch-traffic-from-an-android-application

Comment: @4rigener Considering that nearly all traffic is nowadays TLS encrypted having a proxy in between the connection that sues an untrusted certificate can be like there is not internet connection at all. Of course there can be other problems on network level so that the phone never reaches the proxy.