# No internet when setting middleman proxy in wifi connection for http/https requests Android

Tags: android, postman, fiddler, charles-proxy, web-traffic

I have tried many times with 3 different requests capturer services:

- Postman
- Charles
- Fiddler

And none of them have worked for me; I'm trying to capture https/http traffic from my Android device using the 3 services mentioned above but when following all steps until I modify my network to specify a manual proxy, where the IP is the ip of the network in my pc and the port varies from service `(POSTMAN: 5555, Charles: 8888, Fiddler: 8866)`; so when setting it correctly the network on my phone prompts me: *"No internet connection, connect anyway?"*, I click yes, and as expected, I cant connect to anything; been for hours here and yet dont know why is happening with ANY SERVICE, can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some androids apps won't connect through fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler)

Comment: The short answer: HTTPS interception on an unrooted Android device using original apps from Play Store is no longer possible. Unfortunately this is not mentioned in the documentation of the proxies you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Robert I understand now, I had to use an iOS device to acomplish my goal, anyway, if you would like to post your comment as an answer I would definetly accept it

Comment: The answer on the linked question is also from me. From time to time I update it therefore I prefer to not to copy it. Please just upvote it.

Comment: It is not true that you cannot intercept a Play Store app on an unrooted device.

All apps downloaded from the Play Store have an APK file on your device:
adb shell pm list packages -3 -f

And you can save them with the 'adb pull' command.

Then, if they are not obfuscated (and they usually are not), you can decode them, modify them, and rebuild them. I have done it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a third-party DNS server for your PC's network interface, such as Cloudflare (1.1.1.1).

I've been using Charles for years, I ran into the problem for the first time the other day. I don't know what's causing it, but this fixed it.