# how to inspect connect method requests with charles?

Tags: android, http, networking, https, request

**how to inspect android application requests?**

hey I'm trying to capture android network requests using Charles, any post and get requests works fine, but it fails in connect method requests.

when an application trying to request using connect method it just fails I don't know whats wrong

I installed the certificate too but still have problem

how can I inspect connect method requests too?

Comment: Have you correctly installed the root-CA certificate of Charles as system certificate on Android (root required)? Just installing the certificate as user is not sufficient!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some androids apps won't connect through fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler)