# Intercept Android Studio Emulator HTTPS Traffic with Burp Suite (it's like HTTP but with an 'S')

Tags: android-studio, https, burp

I don't even know why I am asking this question as I am sure no one actually knows an answer. I just want to intercept HTTPS traffic with burp suite while using the android studio emulator.

I did everything. Installed the certificate, proxied through android studio, proxied through the phone and android studio, proxied through the phone alone, messed with the certificates, it's all HTTP. all the other traffic gets the usual "Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown". I think the only way to do it is to root the phone somehow and then install a "rooted certificate" (rooting an emulator sounds so dumb...), god knows that won't be easy.

So, if you don't know how to intercept HTTPS traffic on android studio emulator, please suggest a better emulator where you can do that (with a google play store), in the comments.

Comment: You can intercept https traffic for an app on an unrooted device/emulator, but you have to modify the app to allow the user installed custom root CA certificate of the proxy you use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler/62731432#62731432

Comment: On the opposite, rooting an emulator is easy compared to a hardware phone. You need to first boot into write filesystem, since by default all system files are read-only and than add your file manually.
See this answer for more details:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151167/read-only-file-system-on-emulator