# Installing Charles proxy certificate on Samsung

Tags: android, ssl, samsung-mobile, charles-proxy

I have a problem with Charles proxy certificate on Samsung phone. On Xiaomi everything works fine. But when I try to decrypt traffic on my Samsung device I can't do it - SSL handshake with client failed.

I downloaded it from chls.pro/ssl and added in Settings - Biometrics and security - Other security settings - Install from device storage. Not I can see it in User certificates and in View security certificates.

But still I can't decrypt HTTPS traffic. Maybe I'm missing something?

Update: everything works on Xiaomis with Android 6 & 11 and doesn't work on Samsungs with 8 & 11. So it's definitely not related to the OS version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some androids apps won't connect through fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler). The used proxy does not matter for the certificate problem on Android.