# Monitoring Android Apps

Tags: charles-proxy, burp, http-toolkit

I want to monitor some apps trough android emulator and Charles Proxy/Burp Suite/HTTP Toolkit... Although, those apps aren't starting (probably by detecting Charles Proxy etc).

How can I monitor their requests without actually getting blocked? Is there any way to bypass that protection?

Comment: First you should check if you have correctly installed the new root CA certificate on the phone. As this requires root permissions (or a manipulated app) in most cases a not correctly installed certificate is the first problem you have to fix. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am wondering the same...