# I get an error when recording a mobile application

Tags: android, ssl, jmeter, record

I get an error when recording a mobile application.

1. I deleted ApacheJmeterTemporaryRootCA.crt in the Jmeter bin folder.
2. I started
3. A new ApacheJmeterTemporaryRootCA.crt certificate has been created in the Jmeter bin folder.
4. I downloaded the certificate to the phone
5. I also changed the proxy settings in the phone's wifi settings
6. I also start Jmeter and open the mobile application

But now there is an error as shown in the picture

It was working a few months ago
Now such an error occurs

It's ok when I want to record a mobile browser on my phone.
But this error occurs when I want to record a mobile application from the phone

Please help me

> 2022-03-18 15:22:23,777 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: []  Problem with SSL
> certificate for url  for 'firebase-settings.crashlytics.com'? Ensure
> browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert:
> certificate_unknown 2022-03-18 15:22:26,046 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: []
> KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host 'mobile.test.az' in map with
> key (mobile.test.az) 2022-03-18 15:22:26,319 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy:
> []  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'mobile.test.az'? Ensure
> browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert:
> certificate_unknown

[Jmeter mobile application record error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz2k5.jpg)

Comment: Installing an additional root AC certificate requires changes to the app or root permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler/62731432#62731432

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some androids apps won't connect through fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler) It is a different proxy, but the problem is the same, as it is caused by Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to take some extra steps in order to be able to record HTTPS traffic on [android nougat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Nougat) or higher to wit:

   - add the next line to the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element)  section of your app manifest

     ```
     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
     ```
   - create `network_security_config.xml` file under your app [resources folder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) with the following content

     ```
       <?xml version=“1.0” encoding="utf-8"?>
       <network-security-config>
         <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
             <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
             <certificates src="user" />
           </trust-anchors>
         </debug-overrides>
       </network-security-config>
     ```
   - build your app in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)
   - replace the app in the device with the debug .apk from the previous step

   More information: [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)
2. I don't think you should be recording requests to crashlytics.com (unless you're testing crashlytics itself) as well as any other 3rd-party services, all external domains should be excluded from the recording scope via "Requests Filtering" tab of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder):

   [image]

Comment: If this application does not have a source code, but only an apk file, then how do I do it?

Comment: There are tools like [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) which allow editing .apk files. Another option is rooting your Android device and installing JMeter's MITM certificate as system-wide

Comment: I recorded the same phone, the same computer, and the same application a few months ago.
Why is this happening now?

Comment: `add the next line to the application section of your app manifest

android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
create network_security_config.xml file under your app resources folder with the following content

  <?xml version=“1.0” encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
      <trust-anchors>
        <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
        <certificates src="user" />
      </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
  </network-security-config>`

Comment: I did this
But the same problem
I watch this video and did it
[How to Install/Use ApkTool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fSZabapXjg&ab_channel=RockKoder)

Comment: I did this But the same problem I watch this video and did it