# How does Fiddler decrypt https traffic? It works for my iPhone but fails for my Android

Tags: android, encryption, https, ssl-certificate, fiddler-everywhere

Because of [how https works](https://tiptopsecurity.com/how-does-https-work-rsa-encryption-explained/) as the following picture explains I would assume fiddler acts like a **middle-man**, intercept the requests from mobile, decrypt and re-encrypt to the real servers, then decrypt and re-encrypt the responses to mobile. Otherwise how can it capture all the https traffic?

[image: how https works]

I face a problem that fiddler can only capture the https traffic for an app I am developing from my iPhone but fails to capture from my android. My android app always complains "**The server returns invalid data**" for the very first https request. I would assume **the server** here means fiddler. I have not figured why that happened. And I tried many times on my android, occasionally fiddler can capture traffic but when it worked I did not figured out what I did differently. So I have 2 questions here.

1. Does my assumption about fiddler acting as middle-man correct ? Otherwise how can fiddler (or any other app) capture https traffic ?
2. Has anyone experienced the android error I hit? Any idea how to fix it?

[image: android error]

I search SO and find this one [Some androids apps won't connect through fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler) may be related to my question. The answer there said

> The main problem is that if you install the Fiddler root CA
> certificate in Android it is marked as user certificate (not system
> certificate). And unless explicitly configured in an app those user
> certificates are not trusted.

I did remember after I installed the fiddler CA on my iPhone I need to full trust it to make it work. But on Android I can't find a place to trust the CA. But that also can't explain why it works occasionally.

Comment: Yes I read your answer as I added in my question. But I don't think I need a rooted android. As I said occasionally fiddler can capture my https traffic.

Comment: Please re-read my answer: It depends on the app. If the app accepts user CA certificates (e.g. Chrome for Android)  then it will work otherwise not. But if you want a device that fully works for intercepting there is only the possibility of a rooted device. The CA certificate itself is fine, it is just the way how you install it.

Comment: @Qiulang did you figure it out? The app i'm using works fine, but i don't see any requests on charles proxy for this app

Comment: @Meir it has been a while but I remembered I just can't make android work, please check this discussion I had on fiddler support https://community.getfiddler.com/support/discussions/topics/12000028218

Comment: Note that the figure in this question is partially wrong as it only considers RSA encryption. But since a few years https server certificates more and more use elliptic curve cryptography instead of RSA. And in addition Diffie-Hellman (DH) key agreement protocol is used, so the session key is never transmitted encrypted from cleint to server.