# How to decompile Android app APK and show codes

Tags: android

I want decompile **APK** file and see **API endpoints**. 
I can get **classes.dex** file and when open this application with **jadx-gui** not show me any `fragments`! 
Show all of files without `fragments`! 
I'm sure in this project use some `fragments` and **call APIs** into `fragments`! 
But not show me `fragment` classes?
You can download **classes.dex** file from here : [DownloadDexFile](https://www.file.io/TS4r/download/pltiom90TrPn)

How can I show API endpoints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the file **classes.dex** you have is *obfuscated*. For reference https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#obfuscate

While the `Activity` files are not obfuscated, to be in the Manifest file etc. the `Fragment` files are.

In order to analyze, you can do the following:

1. Using the `dex2jar` utility from https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases
2. Openingn the resulted jar file in `Java decompiler` http://java-decompiler.github.io/

Go to Navigation - Open Type... and type in `Fragment`, double click the 1 matching type to open it. Close the dialog.

Go to Navigation - Open Type Hierarchy... and you will see the following, for your **classes.dex** input file:

[image: Hierarchy type shown]

Comment: Thanks my friend, I can open file with JavaCompiler, but how can I know this obfuscate classes are for android package for this app package?

Comment: Well, those are files inside your provided **classes.dex** file.

Comment: Can I see this codes without obfuscate ? I want get API endpoints

Comment: If you mean, to see *MyFragment* instead of *a*, then the answer is no, not possible without having the *deobfuscation mapping* from application developers. What exactly do you mean by *API endpoints*?

Comment: I want see API endpoints, such as http endpoints to get data from server. I want see how this application connect to server with endpoints

Comment: In this question, you were asking for fragments. API endpoints is a totally different question, not the one you have written. You can try to identify "http" strings in the decompiled source. I can see those: `https://irc.fda.gov.ir/content/Images/CountriesFlag/`
`https://irc.fda.gov.ir/AttachmentApi/LoadAttachment?id=`
`https://cafebazaar.ir/app/`
`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=`
`http://support.ttac.ir/`
`http://www.samansalamat.com`

Comment: Can you say me which file have this addresses? in values/string.xml I can't find this urls . thanks

Comment: Open the .jar file in the `Java decompiler`, select `Search` ->`Search...`, select only `String Constant` and enter **http**. There may be more than one occurence in the file, and some of the occurrences are probably not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in API endpoints / network traffic then why do you ask for Fragments? Network requests can not be performed on the UI thread, therefore the chance to find them in UI code is low.

For obfuscated apps you simply have to put more effort in it to understand how it works. Note that Jadx-Gui allows you to rename classes and methods, if you have identified important code so you can give it meaningful names.

Alternatively you can try to make the app run on a rooted phone with disabled https certificate checking, for details see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978).

Or alternatively on a rooted phone you can use [Frida](https://frida.re) (if the app does not implement anti-hooking) respectively frida-trace to intercept API calls to common Android/Java network requests like [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection).