# Using mitmproxy to find private API (Android apps)

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, mitmproxy

Starting my journey as a dev, one goal is to create an app that gets data from another app (points of a loyalty program), and an interesting approach would be using mitmproxy to see where the API comes from.

I managed to setup mitmproxy on my PC, and managed to connect my phone to the service through the proxy settings, and miproxy sees my web activity perfectly.

EXCEPT for the apps. All apps will not even connect to the web, as if there is no connection, but I can access the web I Chrome still. The CA-certificate is set as a "user" cert on my phone, maybe it has to be a system cert?

Seen some tutorials using an iPhone, seems to work fine there. Anything I might be missing?

Comment: Please see my answer on a very similar topic here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll dive into it more and see if I come to a solution!