# Inspecting Android Phone's Cellular and Wifi Network Packets

Tags: android, mitmproxy, burp, certificate-pinning

I want to intercept my android phones network requests. Not only browser but also application requests like twitter applicaton etc. Cellular network requests would be great but Im ok to wifi connected requests. Without installing root would be also great.

I tried connecting with burp suite or mitmproxy but certificates only works on chrome browser. mitmproxy gives errors like this "Client TLS handshake failed. The client does not trust the proxy's certificate for android-context-data.googleapis.com (OpenSSL Error([('SSL routines', '', 'ssl/tls alert certificate unknown')]))". How can i intercept my phone's cellular and wifi requests?

Comment: Android apps do not accept user installed certificates. You need a rooted device and install the proxy cert as system cert and then hope that the app does not do certificate pinning. More details can be bound in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978

Comment: Thanks bro. Do you have any idea how to inspect cellular data? All the apps I have seen require connection to the same network. How can I be on the same network and use cellular data at the same time?

Comment: Use mitmproxy in wire guard mode on a server that is accessible from the Internet (public IP). If you then activate Wire guard with the mitmproxy server as target and you are on cellular only you will see cellular data.  But I don't think that will include VoLTE data and similar low level protocols.