# Fiddler doesn't work because Chrome and Edge don't trust fiddler certificate

Tags: google-chrome, certificate, fiddler

Fiddler doesn't work recently because Chrome and Edge don't trust fiddler certificate which expires in 2025. So fiddler certificate is valid. The chrome version is
Version 123.0.6312.59 (Official Build) (64-bit). But I don't think that is due to chrome because Edge has the same problem. I have another machine with same fiddler version and chrome version and it works. My OS is Windows 10.

**In fiddler:**

## Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom

25  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   activity.windows.com:443    0           svchost:6352
26  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   stackoverflow.com:443   0           chrome:21232
27  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   analytics.google.com:443    0           chrome:21232
28  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   [www.google.com:443](http://www.google.com:443)  0           chrome:21232
29  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   stackoverflow.com:443   0           chrome:21232
30  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   accounts.youtube.com:443    0           chrome:21232
31  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   clients4.google.com:443 0           chrome:21232
32  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   stackoverflow.com:443   0           chrome:21232
33  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   t0.gstatic.com:443  0           chrome:21232
34  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   [www.google.com:443](http://www.google.com:443)  0           chrome:21232
35  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   stackoverflow.com:443   0           chrome:21232
36  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   play.google.com:443 0           chrome:21232
37  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   stackoverflow.com:443   0           chrome:21232
38  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   slack.com:443   0           slack:5936
39  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   play.google.com:443 0           chrome:21232
40  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   play.google.com:443 0           chrome:21232
41  200 HTTP    Tunnel to   [www.google.com:443](http://www.google.com:443)  0           chrome:21232

**Error message:**
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

**certificate**
Common Name (CN)    *.google.com
Organization (O)    DO_NOT_TRUST
Organizational Unit (OU)    Created by http://www.fiddler2.com
Common Name (CN)    DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot
Organization (O)    DO_NOT_TRUST
Organizational Unit (OU)    Created by http://www.fiddler2.com
Issued On   Friday, March 15, 2024 at 7:00:03 AM
Expires On  Saturday, March 15, 2025 at 7:00:03 AM

Comment: Make sure you have installed the certmaker plugin for Fiddler as mentioned in the first section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978). Also make sure to clear browser cache after switching to Fiddler.