Burp Suite not intercepting android APKs
I have and AVD running connected to burpsuite on 127.0.0.1:8080. I also have the certificate
installed.

When I try to intercept my app (made in Android Studio) everything works perfectly.

The problem comes when I try to intercept any APK installed. It acts like I don't have any internet connection
Here is an example with What's App

I tried to reinstall Android Studio to The Latest Version (Koala | 2024.1.1     3.2-8.5)
I also tried to reinstall the certificate But nothing works in my favor

I found the solution but I cannot post it because I got answer Banned.
Here is it:
https://pastebin.com/qNF16WLP
Upvote this so I can post it again

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62730978/150978 (different proxy, same problem). Also apps can perform certificate pinning (AFIR WhatsApp does). In such a case it doesn't matter where and how you install the proxy certificate.

Hope you're doing well. This "error" is to prevent hacker from intercepting Network traffic, this security measure is called SSL Pinning. And here is a few things you can do.
Root the device, then, install JustTrustMe magisk module. (This is going to make your certificate like a is installed by the system, and not by the user).
Use Frida server to bypass SSL Pinning.
