Android packers protection against patching
There are some APKs on Google Play that are packed by so called packers to obfuscate their bytecode and make more difficult them to reverse engineer. I've made a quick study of the countermeasures and found several articles of researchers that are trying to recover DEX code of the packed program.
My question is more simplier (I hope). I don't need to recover code and reverse its logic: all I need is to know what kind of data the program exchanges with external servers. To do it, I need to patch APK with some kind of tool like apk-mitm and then tools like mitmproxy or burp can be used. But apparently there is some kind of protection - after patching program doesn't even start. Are there any researches that a targeted to fool this protection without recovering the DEX code of a program? Or maybe any ideas of how this protection works?
The packer in question is Ijiami if that matters.

Manipulating APKs of Google is a bad idea as the APK signature is AFAIR checked. better use a rooted device and disable certificate checking and pinning for all Google apps and services: see section "Rooted devices" of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731432/150978

@Robert, of course apk is resigned after it is being patched.
The trick that is described in your post is merely non-working for apps made via flutter framework. So this is not a universal recipe.

Yes, if the app contains an own HTTPS simplementaton them hooks on Java level won't work. I haven't had a flutter app yet, but I assume using Frida it may be possible to hook the functions responsible for TLS certificate verification.

Usually, these packers have a bunch of features like root detection, emulation detection, debugger detection and a lot other weird stuff that is much trickier than SafetyNet - they don't eat their bread for free. So may be it would work but may be not - given that I have found a couple of pretty outdated plugins for Frida to deal with the unpackers I tend to think that it is not gonna work. The time investment into the Frida and all the stuff is pretty much high given that this is not my job - it's just a hobby. Before this I was pretty much happy with things like apk-mitm, reflutter etc.

Seems like you are searching an universal solution that works with all app platforms and all packers. Such a tool does not exists. Use your brain to reverse the apps and find an applicable counter measure to defeat TLS pinning and other anit-reversing measures.
